# Symfony 3.3.9 Listener not calles

Tags: symfony, listener

I have a simple Listener example like the one of
https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#content_wrapper

The example is 1:1

services.yml is the same

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false

    # makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    # AppBundle\:
    #     resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
    #     # you can exclude directories or files
    #     # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
    #     exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository}'
    # controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
    # and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
    # AppBundle\Controller\:
    #     resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
    #     public: true
    #     tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

But the Listener is listed as "Not Called Listeners"

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Might be a priority issue.  The error message implies the listener was recognized and added.  I assume you have the correct method name.  So it is possible than another listener with a higher priority is being called first and then canceling the event.  bin/console debug:event-dispatcher might help.

Answer (score 2):

A class can be auto-tagged if it implements a given interface - this is the case for the EventSubscriber example. If a listener does not have a hint to the container builder (an interface, or a class that it extends), then there's no way to know it should be tagged as a listener, or for which events.

You will likely want to explicitly tag the listener in your configuration, as the example does.

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    AppBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

The subscriber can be deduced, as it has an explicit mapping between an event - `getSubscribedEvents()`, like `KernelEvents::EXCEPTION` and the class method to be run.

As it says on [The Symfony 3.3 DI Container Changes Explained](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html)

> This does *not* work for all tags. Many tags have required attributes, like *event listeners*, where you also need to specify the event name and method in your tag. Autoconfigure works only for tags without any required tag attributes

Comment: he is on 3.3 so tag is not needed he can just do AppBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
tags: ...

Comment: A name, or class name, would work equally well. I copied from the documentation, for speed, and clarity of reference.

Comment: If i read it correctly, I do not have to configure services.yml. In 3.3 the listeners in EventListener Directory are automatically loaded.